# Foundry Dependencies not resolved for deployment of Contract

Tags: solidity, foundry

When I run the following to deploy my contract with foundry

```
source .env
forge script script/CryptoDevs.s.sol:CryptoDevsScript --rpc-url $GOERLI_RPC_URL  --private-key $GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast --verify --etherscan-api-key $ETHERSCAN_API_KEY -vvvv
```

I get this error

```
Compiler run failed
error[6275]: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol" not found
```

Even though I fixed vs code warning like this  `@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol not found: File import callback not supported`

with a .vscode/settings.json file

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "solidity.formatter": "prettier",
    "solidity.defaultCompiler": "remote",
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion" : "latest",
    "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "src",
    "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "lib",
    "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
    "solidity.remappings": [
        "@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/",
        "ds-test/=lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/",
        "forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/"
      ],
}
```

I still get the error. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vs Code and Foundry are different pair of shoes

You need to add additionally a `remappings.txt` file at the root of the foundry project.

```
ds-test/=lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/
forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
```

and then your contract will deploy without problems